# Not able to get output properly aligned

Tags: java, jsp, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

1. List item

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   public class test104 {
       public String[] b=new String[200];
       public String flex(String ps) throws IOException
       {   
           String result="";
           File file=new File("C:\\ProgramData");

           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C",ps);


           pb.directory(file);

           Process p = pb.start();

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   p.getInputStream()));
           String readline;
           //result=reader.readLine();
           int i=0;
           result=reader.readLine();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(readline);
               System.out.println(readline);
               b[i]=readline;
               i++;
               System.out.println("<br>");
           }

           try {
           int exitValue = p.waitFor();
           } 

           catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }


           finally{
           //out.close();  
           } 

           return sb.toString();
       }}

       Print.jsp

       </head>
       <%@ page import="com.test104" %>
       <body>
       <% 
        com.test104 f1=new test104();
        int j=0;
        String k=f1.flex("dir");
        String readline;
        out.println(k);

        %>
   ```

The Output is not aligned in straight line. It should come Like one below the other.!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JglYc.jpg) is the output in a jsp page.

Comment: In your console, are you getting the output in the expected format? or it is same as that in the jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code along the lines of

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(readline);
 }
 someOutputMethod( sb.toString() );
```

will remove all line ends from the input read by reader. You must append line ends `'\n'` after each line or whenever you think necessary.

Comment: Even after adding '\n' the output still remains the same. sb.append(readline+'\n'); Even after this result is till in staircase form. Maybe something is wrong with the append method. Its storing the values in staircase form.

Comment: Use `sb.append('[').append(readline).append(']').append("\r\n");` This should also show you whether spaces are in the input.